# jQuery collect element properties in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, caching, multidimensional-array

```
var arr = [];
$('#menu').children().each(function(){
   arr = $(this).width();
});
console.log(arr);
```

It doesn't work that way, why?
How could I make it to work, so that element propertiers would cache in array for later use?

Comment: A better question would be: Why would it work? Instead of adding new things to `arr`, you're replacing its value with something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
$('#menu').children().each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).width())
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var arr = new Array();
$('#menu').children().each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).width());
});
```

Comment: Better to declare the array like this: `var arr = []`.

Comment: @DidierG. whats the reason for that?

Comment: Basically, you can re-define (almost) everything in javascript. So you can do `Array = function() { alert('You'll never get an array now'); };`. Using `[]` ensures you'll get an array because you can't re-define it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, an assignment is not the same thing as appending to the end of the array. What you're doing is that you're replacing the variable `arr` with the value of `$(this).width()`.

Try this:

```
arr.push($(this).width());
```

That will call a function with the argument which adds it to the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).